# How to find first match in Flux and stop processing in Reactor

Tags: java, reactor

Can't figure out how to stop processing Flux on first match.

This what I have right now:

```
findAll(): Flux<Object>
findStorageId(Relation r): Mono<Long> | Mono.empty()
isPassing(Relation r): boolean

findAll().flatMap(p -> {
  return Flux.fromStream(p.getRelations().stream()).flatMap(r -> {
    return isPassing(r) ? findStorageId(r) : Mono.empty();
  });
})
.handle((Long storageId, SynchronousSink<Long> sink) -> {
  if (storageId != null) {
    sink.next(storageId);
    sink.complete();
  }
})
.next()
.switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Can't find storageId.")));
```

I'm trying to understand how I can interrupt processing of flux when first storageId is found. Right now I see, that first `flatMap` continues to work after finding first match.

Comment: try concatMap instead of flatMap

Comment: @MartinTarjányi instead of first call, second call or both?

Comment: both. note that this will make the whole flow sequential

Comment: @MartinTarjányi looks like it doing the trick. But only for subsequent flatMap. For some reason it still writing to the logs info about sending objects from parent Flux after finding first match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that flatmap is using using concurrency and prefetch is more than 1.
In this case if you dont want to call the database many times but one by one you need to use concatmap with prefatch 1.

```
  public static final String TO_BE_FOUND = "B";

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    Mono<String> storageId =
        Flux.just("A", "B", "C", "D", "A")
            .doOnNext(id -> System.out.printf("processing: %s\n", id))
            .concatMap(s -> findStorageId(s),1)
            .next()
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Can't find storageId.")));
    storageId.subscribe();
  }

  private static Mono<String> findStorageId(String s) {
    return TO_BE_FOUND.equals(s)
        ? Mono.just(s + UUID.randomUUID()).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        : Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).flatMap(aLong -> Mono.empty());
  }
```

in this case concatmap with prefetch 1 will request elements 1 by one and it will wait for the response.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked out using `flatMap → next → onError`, the `handle` is not needed.

- `flatMap`: the method returns a Mono of `String` or `empty`
- `next`: returns the first or empty if `flatMap` always returned empty
- `onError`: error handling according to your example

this means that your example should work like you posted it and you don't even need to call `handle`

**Example code:**

> we log before we pass it to `flatMap`, that way we can check if the stream is processed further after the first non empty mapped `Mono`

```java
    public static final String TO_BE_FOUND = "B";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mono<String> storageId = Flux.just("A", "B", "C", "D", "A")
                .doOnNext(id -> System.out.printf("processing: %s\n", id))
                .flatMap(s -> findStorageId(s))
                .next()
                .switchIfEmpty(
                        Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Can't find storageId."))
                );

        storageId.subscribe(id -> System.out.printf("storageId found: %s\n", id));
    }

    private static Mono<String> findStorageId(String s) {
        return TO_BE_FOUND.equals(s) ? Mono.just(s + UUID.randomUUID()) : Mono.empty();
    }
```

**Output when `TO_BE_FOUND = "B"`:**

> The `Flux` will not be processed further after the firs `storageId` was found.

```
processing: A
processing: B
storageId found: B85bcdbcb-2903-4962-96ab-b3a97b0c091f
```

**Output when `TO_BE_FOUND = "X"`:**

```
processing: A
processing: B
processing: C
processing: D
processing: A
12:52:22.555 [main] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find storageId.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find storageId.
```

Comment: Thanks, but you skipped part with subsequent flux. After switching to simple flatMap, I still see in logs it processing all entries.

Comment: Hm, strange. Just updated your example to mine version and it works. But when I'm receiving Flux from DB, then it goes through all values no matter what.